# Java Expression Types

Tags: java, types, expression

Given the following statement. "0"+"123".charAt(5) ;
what would the type of the expression itself be? Would it be a String or would the exception cause it to not have a type?

Comment: `."charAt` is a syntax error.

Comment: @immibis noooo he should guess first! ;)

Comment: please correct your syntax first and  compile it to see the output.Then if you face any problem post it here

Answer (score 1):

I'd expect a compilation error.

---

Now the question has been edited, I would say the "type" of the expression would be `String`, and the result of executing the expression would be a `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

I suspect the original question was checking your understanding of [operator precedence](http://bmanolov.free.fr/javaoperators.php).

You may be interested to note the differences in this code, which compiles successfully:

```
String s = "0" + "123".charAt(5);
char c = ("0" + "123").charAt(5);
```

N.B. either line will throw `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` if executed alone.

Comment: Please let the OP guess why, since this seems to be an assessment question rather than an actual programming problem :)

Comment: Sure thing.  He might have worked it out by trying to compile it... do you think he's in an exam right now?  And what kind of assessment asks a question like this?

Comment: Hmm, it might be one of the Oracle certifications. I had those types: topic is concurrency, you are presented some code and the question is "what is the result?". Answer: it doesn't compile because theres a semicolon missing ;)

Comment: This was an exam question a few days back. Where the solution was that the type would be a String. However i disagree and think the type would be an exception. I know it would be a compilaton error so i thought i'd ask here to see if you guys had any suggestions if you were asked the question what the type the expression was

Answer (score 1):

There ae several Issues and I am guessing what you like to archieve so:

I guess u mean the String "0+123" and the function charAt(int index). The function returns a char object.

If i am wrong an you mean the expression as it is right now, there would be a error:

- String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote
- cannot be resolved as a type

tried it like you wrote in eclipse.

```
Object test = "0"+123."charAt(5);
```

refactored it like this:

```
static Object test = "0"+123;    
System.out.println(((String) test).charAt(5)); // would be still an exception: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 5
```

Even if you change the property value to "0+123" its still the same exception.

Hope it helps

Comment: Edited the question now, ment to wrote "0"."123".charAt(5);

This was an exam question a few days back. Where the solution was that the type would be a String. However i disagree and think the type would be an exception. I know it would be a compilaton error so i thought i'd ask here to see if you guys had any suggestions if you were asked the question what the type the expression was

Comment: You can't concatenate java Strings with `.`

Comment: But even if the string would be concatinated with '+', there would be still an exception. Also the return type of charAt() is still char. so string is definetly wrong. See: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_charat.htm